# Running cron in Docker works but error all the time "/bin/sh: root: command not found"

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, centos7

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y install crontabs
COPY --chmod=0644 dockerfiles/crontab /etc/cron.d/server-cron
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/server-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD crond && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

What is inside of the `crontab` file is as follows:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

When the container is up & running I can see the cron server working properly because the `tail -f` is printing `Hello world` to the console but is also printing the following error:

> /bin/sh: root: command not found

I have searched on Google but nothing I have found is Docker-related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073038/cronjob-says-bin-sh-1-root-not-found
- https://rhosted.blogspot.com/2010/04/crontab-error-binsh-root-command-not.html
- [Cannot run bash script from crontab when it works from command line bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531098/cannot-run-bash-script-from-crontab-when-it-works-from-command-line-bash)

(and many more)

Is there a way to get rid of this error while in a Docker container or I just should ignore it and leave it alone?

Comment: I think the first question you link to on [ubuntu.se] answers this – Docker doesn't know anything in particular about cron.

Comment: you deleted a Q about crontab a minute ago. I was writing a comment to recommend posting such questions at [unix.se]. (Unless there is now a SE site specific to Docker). My comment was going to be "some versions of `cron` will email all std-out/std-err output to the owning user's email account (just locally) . I'm not sure if your `root` cron entry would send email to `root` or to your "personal" account. Just try running `mail` from the cmd=line and if you get something besides `cmd not found`, then you'll have to learn how to use your local mail client (AND possibly how to use for root).

Comment: @shellter thanks, yes the question was closed and that's why I removed it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR; Remove this line from your Dockerfile**:

```
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/server-cron
```

**Longer explanation**:

You are essentially trying to run the cronjob twice.

When this is run the Dockerfile, you are adding a **system cronjob**, since `crond` will run whatever is defined in that directory:

```
COPY --chmod=0644 dockerfiles/crontab /etc/cron.d/server-cron
```

When this is run the Dockerfile, you are creating a **user cronjob**:

```
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/server-cron
```

So what you're seeing is the second cronjob (the one loaded by crontab) fail. As explained in the first link you posted. Cronjobs loaded with crontab have a different format and should not have the user defined (they are always run as the user that created it).

But then you're also seeing the first cronjob (the file defined under `/etc/cron.d`) succeed because it is in the correct format, that defines the user.